# Получить в респонс значение переменной

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Предположим, у меня есть запрос

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "cancel.php" ,  
    success:function(data) {
      handleData(data); 
   }
});
```

Что надо сделать в пхп файле, чтобы в response(data) вернулся еще дополнительный ключ со значением, которое я получаю в пхп(cancel.php).

Comment: `echo $variable`?

Comment: Ну то есть мне надо чтобы ключ был в обьекте типа -
Ovject:
call_id: "57279eda467f1_952571"
code: 0
data: Object <----------- тут
message: ""
status: "ok"
time: "0.45s"
type: ""
uid: 3650435

Comment: недостаточно информации. Предоставьте пример выполнения `cancel.php` и желаемый результат. И не в комментарии.

Comment: в функции к которой обращаешься напиши return Obj;
Перед этим вкинь в переменную Obj все тебе нужное, и получишь json - в переменную data в аякс запросе;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.get("cancel.php", function(data) {
    // data.message
    // data.call_id
    // data.time
}, 'json');
```

А на стороне сервера в php

```
exit(json_encode(array('call_id'=>1111, 'message' => 'aaa', 'time' =>  '0.45s')));
```

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал.